# laravel 4.2 get data from Object in json response to populate dropdown

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

hello so i have two dropdown list the first one contains my main categories and the second one is containing the sub categories based from the chosen main category to do this i tried using ajax and json. in my view here is the code for the dropdown list

```
<div class="input-field col s10 offset-s1" style="margin-top:40px;">
    <h6>Main Categories</h6>
    <select name="category" id="category">
        @foreach($mCategories as $list)
            <option value="{{$list->maincategoryid}}">{{$list->maincategoryname}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s10 offset-s1" style="margin-top:40px;">
    <h6>Sub Categories</h6>
    <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</div>

<script>

    $('#category').on('change' , function(e){
        console.log(e);

        var cat_id = e.target.value;

        //ajax
        $.get('ajax-subcat?cat_id=' + cat_id , function(data){
            console.log(data);

            $('#subcategory').empty();

            $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj)
            {
              $('#subcategory').append('<option value="' + subcatObj.Object.subcategoryid +'">' + subcatObj.subcategoryname +'</option>');
            });

        });
    });

</script>
```

i have also included the script that would call an ajax whenever the 'Main category' dropdown is changed. the code for that ajax is in my route and looks like this

```
Route::get('ajax-subcat' ,function()
{
$cat_id = Input::get('cat_id');
$subcategories = DB::table('nsa_subcategory')
                ->where('maincategoryid' , '=' , $cat_id)
                ->get();
return Response::json($subcategories);

});
```

basically, it just returns the subcategory based from the main category chosen by the user. Coming back to my view, when the user changed the value of the main category, the json response im having in my console is this, 
[image]

these data are actually correct. What i am trying to do is to access the object to get the subcategoryid and subcategoryname then display it inside a dropdown list. but so far, with my codes in my view, i cannot populate the subcategory dropdown. any ideas what im doing wrong with my codes? thanks for any help

Comment: What you have got in data variable?

Comment: im getting objects based from input of the user in the main category dropdown. you can see it with the image attached. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the conrtoller JSON Response like this.

```
 Route::get('ajax-subcat' ,function()
  {
    $cat_id = Input::get('cat_id');
    $subcategories = DB::table('nsa_subcategory')
            ->where('maincategoryid' , '=' , $cat_id)
            ->get();

    return Response::json(array('result' => true,'data' => $subcategories),200)->setCallback(Input::get('callback'));
  });
```

Change Your JS in following way

```
 <script>

$('#category').on('change' , function(e){
    console.log(e);

    var cat_id = e.target.value;

    //ajax
    $.get('ajax-subcat?cat_id=' + cat_id , function(data){
        console.log(data);

        $('#subcategory').empty();

        $.each(data.data.subcategories, function(index, subcatObj)
        {
          $('#subcategory').append('<option value="' + subcatObj.subcategoryid +'">' + subcatObj.subcategoryname +'</option>');
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: hi i seemed to have a problem in the json response saying `syntax error, unexpected ','`

Comment: @BourneShady the issue was the additional closing  bracket after $subcategories  i have edited the answer try now

Comment: tried it but still can't populate dropdown :| btw you forgot `});` tags in the json response

Comment: @BourneShady try using $('#subcategory')
    .find('option')
    .remove(); instead $('#subcategory').empty();

Comment: hi i did that but same output. i added an `alert()` inside the `$.each` and it wasnt triggered?

Comment: Can yo do alert(JSON.stringify(subcatObj)) and tell me what it is alerting

Comment: hello. i added it inside the `$.each` and it wasnt triggered as well no output from the alert

Comment: @BourneShady that means there is an error is javascript check your console for javascripts errors

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
 $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj) {
     $('#subcategory').append('<option value="' + subcatObj.Object.subcategoryid +'">' + subcatObj.subcategoryname +'</option>');
 });
```

to

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $('<option value="' + data[i].subcategoryid + '">' + data[i].subcategoryname + '</option>').appendTo("#subcategory");
}
```

and

```
$.get();
```

to

```
$.getJSON();
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer! i did this but it was not able to populate the dropdown? any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any other `#subcategory` on the page? An ID is allowed once in a page, so check that. The code seems right.

Comment: @BourneShady i have added some changes try and see if you get your desired output

Comment: @TahaPaksu should i delete the `<option></option>` in my `#subcategory`?

Comment: `$("#subcategory").empty()` does that. You may write there "Please select a category first" if you want.